# Tengo un problema con UIImagePickerController XCODE SWIFT 5, cuando tengo SourceType = .camera

Tags: ios, xcode

Mirad estoy usando uiimagepickercontroller y cuando el usuario selecciona el modo .photolibrary para coger una foto de su dispositivo funciona perfectamente pero cuando usa .camera, captura una foto y después le sale a abajo retake a la izquierda y use photo a la derecha pero no puede hacer clic en ellos ni retroceder.

Se bloquea en esa pantalla y tiene que reiniciar la aplicaciíon.

RECALCAR QUE SE ABRE UN DIALOGO PREGUNTADO SI QUIERE COGER DE LA GALERÍA O HACER FOTO. CUANDO SE COGE UNA FOTO LA PONGO EN UNA TABLEVIEW.

Dejo esto:

@objc func abrirGaleria(_ action: UIAlertAction) {

```
     let vc = UIImagePickerController()
     vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
     vc.allowsEditing = false
     vc.delegate = self
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }

@objc func hacerFoto(_ action: UIAlertAction) {

  let vc = UIImagePickerController()
    vc.sourceType = .camera
    vc.allowsEditing = false
    vc.delegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo
    info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if (info[.originalImage] as? UIImage) != nil {
        // AQUI TENIA MI CODIGO PERO LO BORRE POR PRIVACIDAD SI SE REQUIERE LO PONDRIA
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Espero algún consejo o ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a colocar el dismiss debajo! 
Me ocurrió algo parecido y así es como lo solucione.

```
if (info[.originalImage] as? UIImage) != nil {
        // AQUI TENIA MI CODIGO PERO LO BORRE POR PRIVACIDAD SI SE REQUIERE LO PONDRIA

        }
      dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```